# I have the user input a check number, I want to accept a CR as '0"

Tags: python-3.x

I want to have a CR or null be accepted as zero.
This is the code I use to verify entry is integer, if I type 0 it works but if I just hit ENTER key it does not accept it.

```
while True:
    try:
        Checkno = int(input("Enter Check number, if none Enter 0"))
        #Checkno should be valid integer 0 is ok
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        #better try again... Return to the start of the loop
        continue
    else:
        #Checkno was successfully parsed!
        #we're ready to exit the loop.
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `input()` strips the trailing newline. Hitting *Enter* returns an empty string. You can use an interesting property of `or` to fix this. It will short circuit on the first True thing and resolve to that value. `"foo" or "bar"` is `"foo"`, while `"" or "bar"` is `"bar"`. In your example,

```
while True:
    try:
        Checkno = int(input("Enter Check number, or Enter for 0: ").strip() or 0)
        #Checkno should be valid integer 0 is ok
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        #better try again... Return to the start of the loop
        continue
    else:
        #Checkno was successfully parsed!
        #we're ready to exit the loop.
        break
print(f"using {Checkno}")
```